# Can't figure out why block won't float

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with CSS floating

Here you can see what it looks like:

http://migo.no/help/help.php

Basically, I have two `div`s and I need the last one to float left. It's important that the last `div` floats left.

HTML code:

```
<div id='wrapper'>

    <div id='block1'>block1</div>
    <div id='block2'>block2</div>

</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
}

#block1 {
    background: yellow;
}

#block2 {
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
```

I don't understand why it won't float left, and I have been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Best of regards,
Alexander

Comment: Do you want to make `#block2` on the left side of `#block1` or do you want it to be exactly on the right side of `#block1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you close the wrapper div? Also you don't have block 1 floating left. from your link it appears that Block 2 is floating left. Do you have a more descriptive Idea of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: block 1 does not have float becouse i want block 2 left of block 1, and i need this becouse in my code i need the last block of two , to float left, not the first one, but the second one.

Comment: if you want one to sit next to the other then they both have to be floated, otherwise block one will assume 100% width. Regardless of what others tell you you don't need to specify width. float them both and you'll achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

`block2` is clearing  `block1` and floating left. If you want `block2` to show up on the left side of `block1` you'll need to either make `block2` come before `block1` in the html, or float `block1` to the right. Please be sure to read through [the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats).

Comment: If you already knew that `block2` was floating left, why did you state in your question, "I dont understand why it wont float left, and i have been trying to figure this out for a while now."?

Answer (score 0):

The div *is* floating left.

If you want the divs to be beside each other, you'll have to specify a width for them both and set them both to float left, like Jason suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't really need the width for the blocks (1 and 2), but you can use it if it's necessary for the crossbrowser. What you have to do is to float the `block1` to the left side also.

```
#block1 {
float:left;
    background: yellow;
}
#block2 {
    float: left;
    background: green;
}
```

I just did test it on my machine (FFox, IE7, 8 and 9) and it's working fine, once you float the `block1` to the left side.

Which Browser are you using for this? and are you using the Standard or the Quirksmodus?

Answer (score 0):

Set "float:left" to 1st div also which should solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

This way it works:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style>
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
}

#block1 {
    background: yellow;
}
#block2 {
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='block2'>block2</div>
    <div id='block1'>block1</div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score -1):

`Floats` usually need an explicit `width` set.

If you want both `div`s beside each other, then you need to give `width`s to each and `float` then both.

Also, `overflow: hidden;` will clear the `float`, so if you are expecting the `div` to `float` outside the `wrapper`, it won't happen.

Comment: i allready tried that, now they both have width, still they dont float

Comment: Thanks @zzzzBov. Agreed.  That's why I wrote *Floats **usually** need an explicit width set*.  In many contexts you will need to set the width to achieve the desired result.  Thanks for the clarification, though.  In the future, I think it helps for people (those answering and those reading) to know why something is marked incorrect.